# How can I dynamically refer to a child class from the super class in Python?

Tags: python, inheritance, abstract-class, pylance

Consider this situation:

```py
class Foo(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def some_method(self):
        return

class Bar(Foo):
    def some_method(self, param):
        # do stuff
        return

class Baz(Foo):
    def some_method(self, param):
        # do stuff differently
        return
    
def do_something_with_obj(some_obj: Foo):
    some_param = 'stuff'
    some_obj.some_method(some_param)

def main(cond):
    if cond:
        obj = Bar()
    else:
        obj = Baz()

    do_something_with_obj(obj)
```

I get an `Expected 0 positional arguments` error when I try to call `some_method()` under the `do_something_with_obj()` method. Of course, this is because I'm essentially calling the abstract method. My question is, how can I dynamically refer to the child class method since I have to choose the right child class based on some condition beforehand?

Comment: Please post **the full error message including the stack trace**. Not a vague description of it!

Comment: Wait, this isn't an actually Python error, this is due to some static analysis tool? mypy, pycharm, etc?

Comment: I don't get that error when running that code (and adding `from abc import ABC, abstractmethod`).

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't produce a stack trace as it's being treated as a warning rather than an exception. 

(variable) some_param: Unknown
Expected 0 positional argumentsPylancereportGeneralTypeIssues

Comment: There is a fundamental problem here, your abstract method should have the `param` parameter, or else you break Liskov Substitution Principle.

Comment: @mesllo **because it isn't an actual error**. This is a warning from a static analysis tool (which you've failed to mention or identify). But again, the fundamental problem is that `def some_method(self):` should be `def some_method(self, param):`

Comment: Unless you add a default value to `param` in the subclasses.

Comment: Sorry I should have been much more specific. It's a warning reported by Pylance I think.

Comment: How do you intend to resolve this problem by knowing how to refer to the child class from the super class? That sounds like an XY problem to me. Executing the code already works as-is.

Comment: As I understand it, both sub-classes overload the abstract method which is not allowed in Python right? Could also be the reason why it's being raised.

Comment: @mesllo no, there is no problem with subclasses *overriding* the abstract method. Python *doesn't have method overloading*, so I assume that is what you meant. Again, fundamentally, your method signature in `Foo` should have the extra parameter, otherwise, PyLance is going to correctly complain that your subclasses are broken (indeed, I think it should be doing that already) because your subclass method signatures are incompatible with the superclass method signature.

Comment: I understand. Will reconsider this design then.